# JDBC connection to MySQL and Sybase database at same time

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sybase

I am trying to retrieve data from SYBASE database and copy retrieved data in a table in MySQL. I am able to connect both databases separately (i.e) using jTDS driver for SYBASE and Jdbc_driver for MySQL.

Now I want to connect both databases simultaneously in a single program. But I confused what should be written in `Class.forName()`.

I have used `Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);` for MySQL and `Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");` for SYBASE.

**Sybase:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a;
    String b;
    String c;

    try {  
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                "jdbc:jtds:sybase://10.159.252.29:4100/fmdb","sa","Changeme_123");  

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("selecttbl_alm_log_2000000000.Csn,"
                + "tbl_alm_log_2000000000.IsCleared,"
                + "tbl_alm_log_2000000000.Id"
                + "From fmdb.dbo.tbl_alm_log_2000000000"
                + "Where IsCleared = 0"); 

        while(rs.next()) {
            a = rs.getString(1);
            b = rs.getString(2);
            c = rs.getString(3);

            System.out.println(a+"  "+b+"  "+c);
        }

        con.close();  
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }  
}
```

**MySQL:**

```
try {
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
    System.out.println("connecting to database");

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    System.out.println("connected to database successfully");

    System.out.println("creating table in given database");

    // stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE newtable "
            + "(id INTEGER not NULL, "
            + "first VARCHAR(255), "
            + "PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";

    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

    System.out.println("created table in database");
}
```

These are just snippets. I am just trying to merge above code.
Help me by telling if this is possible or not and sharing some insights into this.

Comment: `Class.forName(...)` was just used to force loading of the JDBC driver class, so just use it twice. Or just leave it out alltogether, as it is obsolete for most JDBC drivers as of Java 6.,

Comment: I tried mysql program without Class.forName(), it gave an error that no suitable driver found. Does this mean that i have older version of java installed?

Comment: @prateekk Or you are using a very old version of the driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple connections in a single program, can be created like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  try{  
      Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");  
      Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sybase://10.159.252.29:4100/fmdb","sa","Changeme_123");

      Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
      Connection con2 = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

      ///After getting both connections, write your code

      String a;
      String b;
      String c;

      Statement stmt= con1.createStatement();  
      ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select tbl_alm_log_2000000000.Csn, tbl_alm_log_2000000000.IsCleared, tbl_alm_log_2000000000.Id From fmdb.dbo.tbl_alm_log_2000000000 Where IsCleared = 0");  
      while(rs.next()) ///If your query result is single row, use if instead of while 
          {
          a = rs.getString(1);
          b = rs.getString(2);
          c = rs.getString(3);

          System.out.println(a+"  "+b+"  "+c);
          }

      String sql = "CREATE TABLE newtable " + "(id INTEGER not NULL, " + "first VARCHAR(255), " + "PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";
      stmt = con2.prepareStatement(sql);
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

      con1.close();
      con2.close();
      }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
   }    

}
```

Comment: I will try and get back to you. ty

Answer (score 0):

the suggestion is to divide a complex task into smaller and more simple tasks:

1)create a method readDB(int startReading, int endReading)with return as ResultSet

2)create a method writeDB(ResultSet result)

3)create a method createTableDB()

P.S. readDB is close to your first example and have to return the read of db, writeDB have only to write inside a db [some tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-insert-records.htm), and then createTableDB have to make the table on db like you write in your second example.

**pseudo final code, in main**:

```
    createTableDB();
    // it's good to make a loop for next part:
    ResultSet read1=readDB(0,200);
    writeDB(read1);
    ResultSet read2=readDB(200,400);
    writeDB(read2);
    ResultSet read3=readDB(400,....); //to the end of db
    writeDB(read3);
```

this is a realy simple solution, it is not perfect and can be modified according to your needs.